# Golang Oauth2 Get Token Scope

Tags: go

When using Golang's Oauth2 library:

https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2#Token

I exchange the authorisation code for access token and I get back this struct:

```
type Token struct {
    // AccessToken is the token that authorizes and authenticates
    // the requests.
    AccessToken string `json:"access_token"`

    // TokenType is the type of token.
    // The Type method returns either this or "Bearer", the default.
    TokenType string `json:"token_type,omitempty"`

    // RefreshToken is a token that's used by the application
    // (as opposed to the user) to refresh the access token
    // if it expires.
    RefreshToken string `json:"refresh_token,omitempty"`

    // Expiry is the optional expiration time of the access token.
    //
    // If zero, TokenSource implementations will reuse the same
    // token forever and RefreshToken or equivalent
    // mechanisms for that TokenSource will not be used.
    Expiry time.Time `json:"expiry,omitempty"`
    // contains filtered or unexported fields
}
```

Now when I am using this access token in my application, I need to know the scope for which the token was granted.

But I don't see any property or method to get the scope?

How to get the token's scope so I can limit user's permissions based on it?

I can see that the Config struct has Scopes slice:

```
type Config struct {
    // ClientID is the application's ID.
    ClientID string

    // ClientSecret is the application's secret.
    ClientSecret string

    // Endpoint contains the resource server's token endpoint
    // URLs. These are constants specific to each server and are
    // often available via site-specific packages, such as
    // google.Endpoint or github.Endpoint.
    Endpoint Endpoint

    // RedirectURL is the URL to redirect users going through
    // the OAuth flow, after the resource owner's URLs.
    RedirectURL string

    // Scope specifies optional requested permissions.
    Scopes []string
}
```

It seems to me there is no way to get scope from a token though?

Surely the point of scope is that it should be part of the access token in order to validate permissions?

See the spec: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-23

Comment: Does `token.Extra("scope")` provide you with anything useful?

Comment: @TimCooper No. Even though my config has Scopes slice specified token.Extra("scope") returns nil. I don't think scope might not be implemented correctly.

Comment: yes, you can get all raw values via token.Extra method. e.g.  token.Extra("scope"), token.Extra("expires_in")

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick

```
    func GetTokensScope(tokUrl string, clientId string, secret string) (string,error){
        body := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id="+clientId+"&client_secret="+secret+"&response_type=token"))
        req, err := http.NewRequest("POST",tokUrl,body)
        req.Header.Set("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")  
        client := &http.Client{}
        resp, err := client.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            return "",err
        }

        defer resp.Body.Close()
        rsBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        type WithScope struct {
            Scope string `json:"scope"`
        }
        var dat WithScope
        err = json.Unmarshal(rsBody,&dat)
        if err != nil {
            return "",err
        }

        return dat.Scope,err
    }
```